# Disable specific days in jQuery UI datepicker

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker

I want to disable all Mondays in my jQuery calendar and I am using this code :

```
function DisableMonday(date) {
   alert(date);
   var day = date.getDay();
   if (day == 1) {
      return [false] ; 
   } 
   else {  
       return [true] ;
   }
}

jQuery(document).ready(function(){
   alert('test');
   jQuery('.datepicker').datepicker({                   
       beforeShowDay: DisableMonday()

   }); 
});
```

my problem seems to be that `(date)` variable in `DisableMonday()` function is undefined...how can I solve this problem

Comment: You are calling the function without a value, and passing its return value for `beforeShowDay`. Instead, you should be passing the function itself (i.e. `beforeShowDay: DisableMonday`)

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried this? Without using a separate method

```
$(".datepicker").datepicker({
    beforeShowDay: function(date) {
        var day = date.getDay();
        return [(day != 1)];
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

According to [jQueryUI's Datepicker](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-beforeShowDay) API,

[image]

---

Just remove the parenthesis `()` after your `DisableMonday` function :

**Replace :**

```
jQuery('.datepicker').datepicker({                   
    beforeShowDay: DisableMonday()
});
```

**By :**

```
jQuery('.datepicker').datepicker({                   
    beforeShowDay: DisableMonday
});
```

And it will work, take a look at **[Working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Fa8Xx/3462/)**.